# SQL syntax error near

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am using a model to run a query like so:

```
    $tickerHigh = $this->model->ticker('price',$market,'AND buysell=buy','ORDER BY PRICE DESC');
```

And here is my model;

```
    $tickersHigh = $this->db->prepare("SELECT ".$type." FROM trades WHERE market=? " . $buysell  . $order . "");
    $tickersHigh->execute(array(strtolower($market)));
    $tickerHigh = $tickersHigh->fetch();
    if($tickerHigh){
    return $tickerHigh->{$type};    
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'BY PRICE DESC' at line 1 in

I'm not sure why?

Comment: You need to seperate these `market=? " . $buysell  . $order . "`. Try `WHERE market=? $buysell '" . $order . "'`

Comment: Thanks, but now I am receiving: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'buy' in 'where clause'

Comment: I've made an edit to my comment. Reload it. But am having difficulty figuring out where the `AND` comes in. You need to show more code.

Comment: Nothing is showing now :( I'm using the AND because I have 2 options, buy or sell. and I either need one or the other not both at the same time

Comment: and here I was trying to build on the model. I thought the first line of code was the "product of".

Comment: What doe the resulting query actually look like?  From oyur code examples it is not clear what is actually going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an space before `ORDER BY` and before `AND buysell=buy` like this:

```
$tickerHigh = $this->model->ticker("price",$market," AND buysell='buy'"," ORDER BY PRICE DESC");
```

Comment: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'buy' in 'where clause'

Comment: I've edited the code for adding missing quotes " buysell='buy'"